# Unable to upload to generic repository with correct filename using curl

Tags: curl, artifactory

I have a gzip file loaded with some scripts and jars. I tried to upload it to Artifactory generic repository using the below command

```
 curl --insecure -uvaib:AP6yNYCePVfi5Ej8cXx1vq2SuFs -T "./deploy.tar.gz" "https://artifactory.service.apz/artifactory/EVC_Release/AC_2017_11a/deploy.tar.gz"
```

I get the below error message.

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
"status" : 400,
"message" : "Parent AC_2017_11a must be a folder"
 } ]
```

if I remove the name of the artifact from the end, it uploads but the filename becomes the package name

the structure I am looking at is
EVC_Release --> specific release name --> gzip file.

is there an issue with the options or my configuration in Artifactory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to create the folder.

So you should have 2 commands:

```
 curl -uvaib:AP6yNYCePVfi5Ej8cXx1vq2SuFs -X PUT "https://artifactory.service.apz/artifactory/EVC_Release/AC_2017_11a"
 curl --insecure -uvaib:AP6yNYCePVfi5Ej8cXx1vq2SuFs -T "./deploy.tar.gz" "https://artifactory.service.apz/artifactory/EVC_Release/AC_2017_11a/deploy.tar.gz"
```

Any reason why you are not using JFrog CLI? It is much more powerful and user-friendly than what you are trying to achieve.
Once configured, the upload is simply:

```
jfrog rt upload ./deploy.tar.gz EVC_Release/AC_2017_11a/deploy.tar.gz
```